# why filter not apply on angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use `pipe` or filter in Aangular 2. I getting this error:

```
zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'search' could not be found ("<div>
                <ul>
                 <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let tt of todoService.todo| search">
                <row-item [t]='tt'></row-item>
         "): TodoList@2:21 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'search' could not be found ("<div>
```

Here is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WXgdKF2gx9Kpj7eqmDJv?p=preview

`todo-search.ts`

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
name:'search'
})

export class TodoSearch  implements PipeTransform{
transform(value){
  return value.filter((i) =>i.title.startsWith('s'));
}
}
```

I am using filter like this

```
<li *ngFor="let tt of todoService.todo| search">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the pipe to declarations

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,Todo,TodoList,TodoRow,TodoSearch],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

You should also make your pipe safe for `null` values:

```
export class TodoSearch  implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value){
    if(!value) {
      return;
    }
    return value.filter((i) =>i.title.startsWith('s'));
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/m0mnhkSeqajGu72esWMf?p=preview)

Comment: what are things need to add in `declarations`

Comment: @user944513 components, directives and pipes of the current `@NgModule()` that you want to use in other components of the current `@NgModule()`. If you import another module to use components, directives and pipes from there, you don't need to add them to declarations again (they should be in `exports` of the imported module.